# Can not register using sails-generate-auth

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js

i am a newbie api developer. For this i am using sailsjs. For authentication i am using sails-generate-auth. i have followed the doc in the github.

Here what i have done is:

```
// ProfileController:
home: function (req, res) {
Passport
.findOne({ protocol: 'local', user: req.user.id })
.exec(function(err, passport) {
return res.json({
todo: 'home() is not implemented yet! But you are logged in :)',
token: passport.accessToken
});
});
}

//config/policy.js
// '': true,
'': ['passport', 'sessionAuth'],
'Profile': {
'showAll': ['passport', 'bearerAuth','sessionAuth'],
},
'auth': {
'*': ['passport']
}
```

But i can not register. when i click http://localhost:1337/auth/register it  redirects to http://localhost:1337/auth/local/register and says the page you are trying to reach does not exit.

Have i missed something in any file of the code??

Answer (score 1):

The docs arn't detailed enough. Try follow this tutorial: https://www.bearfruit.org/2014/07/21/tutorial-easy-authentication-for-sails-js-apps/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. yes i think the doc is not enough.

I have solved the problem. This occurred for some kind of  negligence. i have forgot to config my config/route.js file.

if you do not config the config/route.js file you will be able to register but the redirection will not happen properly.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a module for sails that will set this all up for you: https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth